# Is there any way to create a tsv response with Lumen/Laravel PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, csv, lumen, rest

I'm creating a REST API with **Lumen PHP**, i want to create a **tsv** response to visualise genomic data.
for example this is the JSON response:

```json
[
{
 "chrom":"3",
"chromStart":"10120",
"chromEnd":"10296",
"exp_id":"GSE43985",
"target":"ESR1",
"biotype":"VCaP_E2",
"score":"0",
"strand":".",
"summitStart":10187,
"summitEnd":10188,
"rgb":"224,168,84"
},
{
"chrom":"3",
"chromStart":"10123",
"chromEnd":"10285",
"exp_id":"GSE98367",
"target":"MAF",
"biotype":"monocyte",
"score":"5.03350",
"strand":".",
"summitStart":10253,
"summitEnd":10254,
"rgb":"168,112,28"
}
]
```

I want to generate a downloaded tsv file like this:

```
chrom   chromStart  chromEnd    exp_id  target  biotype score   strand  summitStart summitEnd   rgb
3   10120   10296   GSE43985    ESR1    VCaP_E2 0   .   10187   10188   224,168,84
3   10123   10285   GSE98367    MAF monocyte    5.03350 .   10253   10254   168,112,28
```